# c# Class Access from Nested Class Confusion

Tags: c#, nested-class

I have created a library class where...

```
public class CircuitLibrary
{
   // Fields, properties, methods, etc.
   ...

   // Nested classes.
   public class Sensor
   {
      // Enums.
      public enum Sensors { Sensor1, Sensor2, Sensor3, ... };

      ...
   }

   public class SerialCommands
   {
      // Fields, properties, etc.
      ...

      // Nested classes.
      public class SensorSettingsCommands
      {
         // Fields, properties, etc.
         ...

         public void SomeMethod()
         {
            ...
            if( Sensor.Sensors.IsOn ) // Doesn't like this. OK if I change to CircuitLibrary.Sensor.Sensors.IsOn. Why?
               ...
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
Cannot access a nonstatic member of outer type
"MyCircuitLibrary.CircuitLibrary.SerialCommands" via nested type
"MyCircuitLibrary.CircuitLibrary.SerialCommands.SensorSettingsCommands"
```

So it looks like it is searching for (and found?) `Sensor` in `SerialCommands`? But if I change it to `CircuitLibrary.Sensor` it now knows it is in CircuitLibrary? When I right-click and "Go to definition" it finds it okay and doesn't say "Couldn't find `Sensor` in `SerialCommands`". If someone could help explain what is going on I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect some of the properties that you've not shown are relevant here. Please try to post a short but *complete* example.

Comment: BTW, [you should not use public nested classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182162.aspx).

Comment: @SLaks: Yes, I read something similar [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9f3ty7f%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) but considered my situation very similar to the described wheel-bearing example. I have a circuit controller which will use sensors (which can only be used on this type of circuit) and each sensor has properties I need to read/write. I have been battling this issue for a while now. :/ I'll open a new post for it; maybe I'll see you there. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `SerialCommands` class has a non-static `Sensor` property.

Since this property is closer to your code than the outer-most `Sensor` class, the compiler thinks you're using the property rather than the class.
Since you can't a use the non-static property without a `SerialCommands` instance, you get an error.

When you write `CircuitLibrary.Sensor`, it works fine, since there is no `CircuitLibrary` property to confuse the compiler.